# OKTA Authentication integration in React Next.js app

Tags: reactjs, next.js, openid-connect, access-token, okta

I am trying to integrate OKTA app into the next.js app. When I integrate OKTA auth using OIDC, I get a JWT session token in the response. I need an Id token and access token in the success response instead of a session token directly.

Is it expected to get only session tokens or are there any config changes that I need to do?
When I integrate react CRA app I get an access token and id token in the success callback.

Is there any way of using a session token instead of an access token?